# JavaScript Function Syntax Explanation: function object.myFunction(){..}

Tags: javascript, syntax

I would consider myself to be reasonably competent with JavaScript and familiar with many of the different ways of achieving the same thing. But today I came across some function syntax which I hadn't seen before:

```
function document.body.onload()
{
    alert('loaded');   
}
```

If I were to write such code I would have done it like this:

```
document.body.onload = function()
{
    alert('loaded');   
}
```

Ignoring the fact that this is not the best way to handle the `onload` event, is this actually valid JavaScript? It appears to causes syntax errors in FireFox (and JSLint), so I am guessing that it is Internet Explorer only syntax? If it is IE only then I would like to remove it but I am concerned that it might have some quirky side effect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`function document.body.onload` is non-standard JavaScript syntax. Use the second format, and fire whomever wrote the original code.

<sub>Don't forget the semi-colon after the end `}`</sub>

```
document.body.onload = function () {
    ...code...
}; //this is easy to miss
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not valid. the `function X() {}` variant requires that the name of the function  only contains letters, digits, '$' and '_'.

If you want to check other syntax, you can [get the standard here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_Language_Resources), but the syntax diagrams in the back of [JavaScript: The Good Parts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742) are much easier to digest.